# NgClick on <li> NgClick inside of it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have following code:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li ng-click="setValue('X')" ng-class="selected === 'X' ? 'active' : 'not-active'"><span>X <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="unselect()"/></span></li>
   <li ng-click="setValue('Y')" ng-class="selected === 'Y' ? 'active' : 'not-active'"><span>Y <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="unselect()"/></span></li>
 </ul>
```

I am switching classes if the value is selected. I would like to add an event on icon (which is only visible when its is selected), however, whenever I click on the icon, two ng-click's are triggered. My question is: how can I disable the ng-click on the parent element, when the row is selected?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add `$event.stopPropagation()` to your inner `ng-click`:

```
<i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="unselect(); $event.stopPropagation();"/>
```

This will prevent the `ng-click` on the parent element from being called.

Comment: Sweet! That works great! Are there any drawback of using this approach?

Answer (score 2):

When you write and event in a DOM element, it's invocation bubbles up to call event attached to all it's parent till `HTML` tags.

You can prevent this occurrence by preventing the event to propagate further. `stopPropagation` does exactly that. You can find, details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

In your, `unselect` function, you can call like this

```
function unselect(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Your original code
}
```